# How to open excel file's read only mode on C#?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, visual-studio

I'm creating dataset from csv excel file and that files is processing while I access it.

It says "[image: Error message]

I need to access it read only mode? This is working code.

```
    private void connect()
{
   try
   {
       if (checkbox1.Checked == false)
       {
          FilePath = @"C:\FILE";
       }
       else
       {
          FilePath = @"\\192.168.0.2\file\"; // 
       }
       strConn = @"Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" + FilePath + @"\;Extensions=csv,txt";
       Connect = new OdbcConnection(strConn);
       Connect.Open();
   }
   catch (Exception Ex)
   {
       MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message);           
   }


 DataGrid1.SelectAll();
 DataGrid1.ClearSelection();


       FileName = ".csv";           
CSVDataSource = FilePath + FileName;
            ReadData(FileName);
            DataGrid1.Update();

    }
```

Comment: if it locked exclusivley - there is no chance to open in with excel. but you can use ms-access for that purpose - if your intention is to store data and display it on the client's screen

Comment: copy the file to another location, then open the copy.

Comment: @dbugger Yes I agree but I have no experience with it. What is the command of this

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: what's the purpose of opening it? Can you not just grab data from it without opening it?

Answer (score 0):

It says it cannot open the file '(unknown)'. The thing about exclusive and permissions is probably just a too general error description. You do not seem to have a valid file path, also you might not be able to open it directly from a network path.
Verify your file path, and if it still not works - copy it to your local machine and try again.